# How to use Python to visualize the comparison of multiple related time series?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, data-visualization

[Comparing predicted data from multiple sources with actual data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzLsf.png)

I am trying to write a Python program which compares predicted points for fantasy football players with actual points in order to see which data provider's predictive algorithm is the most accurate. I have figured out how to visualize the actual and predicted points for a single player as in the above graph. However, not being a statistics expert, I am unsure as to what statistical method(s) to use in order to compute and visualize the comparison of identical data for 500+ players. Ultimately I'd like to end up with one graph which shows the difference between predicted and actual values over the course of an entire season for all players. Can someone please point me in the right general direction in terms of how this would be done theoretically from a statistics points of view? This is a python learning experience/exercise for me and I'm just using the chosen data because I have a personal interest in it. Thanks!

Below is a sample of my code. I realize that it's quite ugly currently and probably needs to turned into function. But this is just a quick proof of concept before I turn it into something more proper.

```
import sqlite3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

player_id = str(12) # This is just player #12, randomly chosen
conn = sqlite3.connect('FPL.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

df_ffs = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM FFScout WHERE player_id ='+player_id,conn)
df_ffs = df_ffs.transpose()
df_ffs.columns = ['FFScout']
df_fff = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM FFFix WHERE player_id ='+player_id,conn)
df_fff = df_fff.transpose()
df_fff.columns = ['FFFix']
df_ffrev = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM FPLReview WHERE player_id ='+player_id,conn)
df_ffrev = df_ffrev.transpose()
df_ffrev.columns = ['FPLReview']
df_foverlord = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM FOverlord WHERE player_id ='+player_id,conn)
df_foverlord = df_foverlord.transpose()
df_foverlord.columns = ['FOverlord']
df_foomni = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM Foomni WHERE player_id ='+player_id,conn)
df_foomni = df_foomni.transpose()
df_foomni.columns = ['Foomni']
df_actual = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM GW WHERE player_id ='+player_id,conn)
df_actual = df_actual.transpose()
df_actual.columns = ['ActualGW']

merged_df = pd.concat([df_ffs,df_fff,df_ffrev,df_foverlord,df_foomni,df_actual], axis =1)
merged_df = merged_df.drop(merged_df.index[0])
print(merged_df.head(25))
merged_df.plot()
plt.xlabel('Gameweek')
plt.ylabel('Points')
```

merged_df dataframe currently look like this (first 25 rows):

```
     FFScout FFFix FPLReview FOverlord Foomni ActualGW
GW1     None  None      None      None   None        0
GW2     None  None      None      None   None        8
GW3     None  None      None      None   None        1
GW4     None  None      None      None   None        5
GW5     None  None      None      None   None        0
GW6     None  None      None      None   None        0
GW7     None  None      None      None   None        0
GW8     None  None      None      None   None        0
GW9     None  None      None      None   None        1
GW10    None  None      None      None   None        5
GW11    None  None      None      None   None        4
GW12    None  None      None      None   None        2
GW13    None  None      None      None   None       12
GW14    None  None      None      None   None        2
GW15     5.1  None      None      None   None        7
GW16     4.5  None      None       4.8    5.2     None
GW17     3.9  None      3.67       6.2    3.3     None
GW18     3.9  None      4.22         5   None     None
GW19     4.4  None      4.63       4.6   None     None
GW20     4.1  None      4.19       6.4   None     None
GW21    None  None      4.25         7   None     None
GW22    None  None      None      None   None     None
GW23    None  None      None      None   None     None
GW24    None  None      None      None   None     None
GW25    None  None      None      None   None     None
```

ActualGW row is the actual points for the player for each gameweek. The other columns are predicted values coming from other data sources for the same gameweek. So basically what I'd ultimately like to do is this x 500 players, but all in one graph (somehow).

Comment: If you can write a code snippet (a minimum working example) that includes a dataframe (similar columns and data structure to your actual data) it would make it easier for us to help. You probably want to plot some "loss function" representing the difference between your predictions and the data, but knowing more about the structure of the data would help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've edited the original question to supply some basic code and dataframe info. I've basically scraped websites for the data and put it all into an sqlite db. Then I'm querying the DB for the info as needed.

Comment: I see. You might want to try concatenating the data for multiple players, and including a column for the ID of the player. Then for each prediction you could compute the squared error (ACTUAL - PREDICTED)^2. One thing you could do is compute the mean squared error by game week and plot across game weeks. If `df` was your dataframe with all players, you could do `df.groupby(axis=0)['se'].mean().plot()` where `'se'` is the squared error variable for a particular prediction. If you have multiple squared errors, e.g., `'se1'`, `'se2'`, you do `df.groupby(axis=0)[['se1', 'se2']].mean().plot()`.

Comment: notice I group by `axis=0`, this is because your game week in your dataframe is the index. if it was column, you'd groupby the column name instead, e.g., `df.groupby('GameWeek')[['se1', 'se2']].mean.plot()`

Comment: Great ideas. You're input around mean squared error has me on the right track I think. I'll go with that for a bit and see how it pans out. Thanks so much for your input!

Comment: @jtorca Solution works great!  
>This is the root mean squared error:  1.4798648586948742  
>This is the mean absolute percentage error:  43.89790398918188  
>This is the mean absolute error:  1.4  
>This is the mean squared error:  2.19